# How to Set the size of alert View?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I have used date picker in alert view. As alert view has default height and width, I want to change that... Any one know that how to do? Please convey..!

Comment: You cant change the width but the height as-
myAlertView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,600, 500);
Try it, May Help

Comment: Use other Values Instead I suggested in CGRectMake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `CGRectMake` parameters with proper values.

```
UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] 
                          initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 20, 320, 400)];
```

You could also subclass `UIAlertView`.

Comment: Ya i have tried it but still facing same problem...
Thanks RaYell for instant reply..

Comment: If `initWithFrame` doesn't work for you then I'd go with `UIAlertView` subclass.

Answer (score 0):

You can't resize the UIAlertView cleanly.

You could change the `.frame` *after* the UIAlertView has been `-show`n, but the buttons will be wrongly placed.

Why not use a [UIPopoverController](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPopoverController_class/Reference/Reference.html) since you're targeting iPad?

Comment: Actually I didnt think on it! Bt its good idea.. I will try it. Thanks.